# A Poll That Is Auto Created For Each Post in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, polling

I'm looking to have a poll at the end of each of our posts that the viewer can vote on.  I don't want to have to manually create a poll for each post.
The only plugins I can find are star ratings.  We're looking for a custom poll that asks something like "Would you consider this article: Pro This, Anti This or Right in the Middle".  Otherwise I have to create a unique poll for each post and manually insert.  We're planning on having dozens of new posts a day.
I've been searching everywhere and cannot find anything like this.  I'm hoping someone has a recommendation.

Comment: Did you consider writing your own plugin for that ? do you have any sample code ? you could easily inject any code to any post , either by creating a child-theme ( `single.php` , `post.php` or with a custom hook on `functions.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I wrote in the comment, you can easily achieve what you want in several ways. For example :

1. Create child theme ( create custom `single.php` or `post.php`or any other alternative )
2. Create a child theme with a custom function in `functions.php` ( see below )
3. create own plugin with custom function and use `the_content` filter ( see below )

```
function whateverContentYouWant($content) {
        if(!is_feed() && !is_home()) { // your conditions if any 
                $content.= "Enjoyed this article?"; // add your content here
        }
        return $content;
}
add_filter ('the_content', 'whateverContentYouWant');
```

That being said, I am not sure this site is the best place to search plugin recommendations. better if you have a more specific code-related issues ( with examples )